# Unrecognized friends in Game Center?

Tags: icloud, accounts, game-center

By chance, I opened my Game Center account settings ("Internet Accounts" on Mac System Preferences, "Game Center" in iOS Settings) and noticed I have 25 "friends" that I don't recall ever adding. They have random/spammy/crude names, I don't use Game Center, and I'm not somebody who would add random people.

I've removed them using the "Remove All" functionality on iOS, but I'm curious if anyone knows how they showed up?

*I do not have logs turned on, unfortunately.*